# Windows gone and ubuntu not working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I installed ubuntu alongside windows 8.1 and i installed correctly by creating partitions and the laptop finally says restart to use ubuntu but when i do , it agains diplays a gnu grub version showing :
-try ubuntu without installing
-install ubuntu
-oem install
-check disc for defects.

also i have no idea where my windows has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the installation media (disk or usb) and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

When your computer boots up, enter BIOS and change the boot settings so that the default device is your hard drive and not your USB or CD.